# DesignInstance not working in Modern UI

Tags: xaml, design-time

```
d:DataContext="{d:DesignInstance vm:MyViewModelSampleData, IsDesignTimeCreatable=True}"
```

works in WPF and WP8, but strangely not in my Windows Store app. In it, I set Items = .... but they never show up in Blend or in VS2012. Any tips?